# Can't change texts in ISCII encoding to unicode

Tags: java, iscii

I have large text files in Hindi languages that use encodings under ISCII - Tamil, Bengali, Kannada, Marathi..
I've failed to find a single working encoder and Java doesn't support ISCII sub-encodings.

Is there another way to encode these? (I've tried iconv, enca)

Comment: It looks like you could create a Map that would translate each [ISCII byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Script_Code_for_Information_Interchange) to UTF-8..

Comment: That means building my own encoder - which I could, but since the translation logic is complex I'd rather look for a stable existing solution and write my own as a last resort..

Comment: @JohnnyBack I'm trying to do the same using C#. Could you please let me know how you were able to solve this issue?